# Want to continuous redirect 302

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

Now i want to continuous redirect my site.

Example: Visitor go to: MyDomain/abc?id=1

They will be redirect 302 to: MyDomain/RandomString1

and continue Redirect to MyDomain/RandomString2

and continue:.... until to MyDomain/RandomString10

with Random string is random string and:

- RandomString1 to 10 is not exist.

Please help me. Bellow attachment is demo
[Here is demo image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bvjhq.png)

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what your looking for but as i understand the question this is what i have to offer

```html
    <?
     $numberofstrings = 1;
     $i = $numberofstrings;
     $string = "url";
     
     while($i < $numberofstrings){
      $i++;
      $currentString = $string . "?id=" . $i;
      header("Location: $currentString")
     }
$id = $_GET['id'];
if($_GET['id'] == 1){
 header("Location: url");
} elseif($id == 2){
 header("Location: url2");
}
    ?>
```